# Launch Activity from Native code

Tags: android, android-ndk

Is there any way to Launch new Activity from Native code? My native activity is the launcher activity.

```
// main.c - launcher activities native code here
void android_main(struct android_app* state)
{
  // launch new activity from here.
}
```